# uploading files from my computer to an ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, server

i'm connected to an Ubuntu server via putty (ssh).
i want to be able to upload files from my computer to the server. 
the file i'm trying to upload is a .zip file, so are there any restrictions for that? 
I'm using windows 7 OS.
please help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends your local operating system you are using.

- If your **local OS is Windows**, you can use `winscp`, but you will have to unzip the archive before moving it to the target Linux server.
- If your **local OS is Linux**, you can use the `scp` or `rsync` command line utility. For example, you can run:

  Using `scp`:

  ```
   scp path/to/file/to/upload user@host:path/to/file/topaste
  ```

  or using `rsync`:

  ```
   rsync -ahvc /path/to/file/to/upload user@host:/path/to/file/to/paste
  ```

  Prefer `rsync` because it's faster and does not re-upload the file if it already exists on the target server. However, `rsync` needs to be installed to both the local Linux machine and target server. On the contrary, `scp` will be pre-installed most of the time and does not require the server to also have it installed, like `rsync` does.

Comment: i'm using windows, and lets say the file is in C:\Users\name of user\documents
is that the correct syntax to type in the ubuntu terminal? 
winscp C:/Users/name of user/documents.filename.zip user@host:path/to/file/topaste

Comment: @jukerok You want to copy the file from windows to the server, so you have to run the command from your local windows machine since your local machine does not run a server (If you run the command from the server you can't reference to your local machine since it's not a server). So download the winscp utility from [here](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

Comment: how to set the port with such connection?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scp` line command to copy a file through `ssh`

```
        scp /path/to/file username@a:/path/to/destination
```

Mode details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh)